# How to fetch datediff number

Tags: mysql, fetch, datediff, days

I've some problem, I have two dates from datepicker and then I want to know the range of date between two datepikers.

```
DATEDIFF('2017-04-30','2017-04-01')
Result : 29
```

Output :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create one table call tblCalendar(calendar), then i just need to make query

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(calender, '%d')) ResultDate 
FROM 
calender 
WHERE 
calender BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30'
```

Result:

```
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,
16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```